# Handlebars.js: Is it possible to pass multiple hashes as arguments to a Handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, template-engine, handlebars.js

Let's say I have declared following helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("linkTo", function(request, params) {
    return window.linkTo(request, params);
});
```

how can I (if possible) do something like this in the view (not correct syntax, just for show purposes)

```
<a href="{{link_to module='products' controller='view', product=product.id artist= artist.id}}">foo</a>
```

the comma just symbolises separation between the two hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, due the way Handlebars.js uses parameters it can't separate multiple hashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your way to putting your parameters into a structure that you can pass as part of an object literal then I know that will work. For example:

```
{ 
  "params" : {
    "module" : "products",
    "controller" : "view",
    "product" : 5,
    "artist" : 25
  }
}
```

Plus this helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("link_to", function(params) {
  var result = "";
  var insertAmpersand = false;

  for (var prop in params) {
      if (insertAmpersand) {
          result += "&";
      } else {
          insertAmpersand = true;
      }

      result += prop + "=" + params[prop];
  }
  return result;
});
```

Can be called like so:

```
{{link_to params}}
```

To generate:

```
module=products&controller=view&product=5&artist=25
```

Obviously you would want to refine that so that things had the right quote marks around it, etc. But would something like that work for you?

Comment: John, this unfortunately doesn't help. I need the request and params to be separate, otherwise the helper doesn't know where the properties belong. Your solution simply assumes that all are part of params. At the moment I have implemented workaround where I prepare request object inside the controller and use the "options" hash for params (filled in dynamically in view's loop). It seems that the answer to my question is "NO" due to the way Handlebars.js uses parameters and has no way of separating multiple hashes.